# Temporary table vs Table variable

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table where I have around 1.5 million+ results that I need to delete.  Previously, I was using a temporary table and this caused the transaction log to increase in size quite quickly.  Problem is, once I have done one result set, I need to move onto another where there is another 1.5 million+ results.  The performance of this is rather slow and I'm wondering if I should use a `table` variable rather than writing a table to the temp database.

**EDIT**

I use the temporary table when I select the initial 1.5million+ records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Side-stepping the table variable vs. temp table question, you're probably better off batching your deletes into smaller groups inside of a while loop. That's your best bet for keeping the transaction log size reasonable.

Something like:

```
while (1=1) begin
    delete top(1000)
        from YourTable
        where ...

    if @@rowcount < 1000 break
end /* while */
```

Comment: I'm guessing that I'd have to have another `delete` at the end of the `while` loop in order to clean up the remainding records?

Comment: How would this work with `Transactions`?  Would I put the begin the `transaction` inside the `while`?

Comment: @Ardman: I don't think so. The while loop exits once the delete removes less than fixed batch size (1,000 records in my example), which should indicate that all of the desired deletes have completed. So, if you're deleteing 1,400 rows, the loop runs twice, removing 1,000 records the first time and 400 the next. 400<1000 triggers the break.

Comment: @Ardman: A transaction outside of the while loop would defeat the purposes of batching the deletes into smaller groups so I'd say you'd want it inside. But if your requirements specify rolling back all 1.5M records if any failure occurs, then outside is your only choice and there's no point in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I prefer using table variables over temp tables, if only because they're easier to use. I find few cases where the use of temp tables is warranted. You don't talk about how you're using temp tables in your routines, but I suggest benchmarking the two options.

Comment: The temporary table is used when I select the 1.5mil+ records.  I then use the temp table to delete records.

Comment: @Ardman: You must have a good reason why you delete from the temp table rather than just deleting the rows directly. Why? Can you give us an overview of your logic?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not deleting from the temporary table.  I use the temporary table in order to get my list of records.  I then use this list to delete the records from tables.

Answer (score 0):

A table variable is often not suitable for such large resultsets, being more appropriate for small numbers. You'd likely find that the table variable's data would be written to tempdb anyway due to its size.
Personally I have found table variables to be much slower than temporary tables when dealing with large resultsets. In an example mentioned at the end of [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Temporary+Tables/66720/) on SQL Server Central using 1 million rows in a table of each time, the query using the temporary table took less than a sixth of the time to complete.
Personally I've found table variables to often suffer performance-wise when I have to join them to real tables in a query.

If the performance is slow it may be at least partly the settings on the database itself. Is it set to automatically grow? What's the recovery model of it?

Comment: Recovery model is `FULL`.  Maybe changing to `SIMPLE` then running the `DELETE` would be quicker?

Comment: It would be quicker, but it would wipe out your existing transaction log. How acceptable that is depends on your business requirements. Is downtime of the DB acceptable? Then you could backup, change the recovery model, run the delete, then put the recovery model back.